# Add rate limiting for a serverless react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am using emailjs to send emails, but I realize users can just spam it.

I am wondering if it is possible to add a rate limiter (like only 1 email every 30 mins) for a serverless react app. I know express has a rate limit package (express-rate-limit) and I am wondering if React also has one? if not, then how would I add a rate limiter to my react app?

Comment: If your app is only a client side app, then you should assume that the user has full control over the client and will be able to bypass any clientside protections you put in. The only way to implement a rate limit would be to do it on the server side.